# make all auto increment integers the same number of digits with leading zeros

Tags: mysql, sql

I was wondering if there was a way to set my id column(auto-incremented) to always have 5 digits using leading zeros in my mysql table. So the first value would be 00001 then 00002 and so on up to 99999 instead of 1,2,3 up to 99999. Thanks

Comment: Where do you want to see the leading zero's? What are you using to display the information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ID column is a numeric value, so it's always going to have the same value.  If you want the integer to be formatted a certain way, then you're going to have to do that formatting as part of the SELECT.  Look at the LPAD function.

[LPAD with leading zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17612920/lpad-with-leading-zero)

Comment: Thanks, that question was exactly what I trying find before I posted, but I couldn't find it. LPAD looks like the right function. Great link

Answer (score 7):

Try adding **ZEROFILL** attribute to the field;

Declaration:

```
`ID` INT(5) ZEROFILL AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL
```

Comment: Now attribute seems like called "Unsigned Zerofill"