# How to random a zero leading string field mysql

Tags: php, mysql, random, sql-update

I'm not sure if you understand my question correctly. So may I explain a bit. I have a customer table which is needed to test with different number (no matter if it real). So this is the script:

**customer_db**

```
+----+------------+
| ID |   NUMBER   |
+----+------------+
| 1  | 0812345678 |
+----+------------+
| 2  | 0812345678 |
+----+------------+
| 3  | 0812345678 |
+----+------------+
.
.
.
|100 | 0812345678 |
```

According to the table. I ran this script:

```
UPDATE customer_db SET number = FLOOR(0812345678 + rand()*1000000);
```

Doing this. I expect the field remains the same format with leading '081' and random the rest 6 digits. **But it's not**. The table becomes these :

```
+----+------------+
| ID |   NUMBER   |
+----+------------+
| 1  | 812246797 |
+----+------------+
| 2  | 816548798 |
+----+------------+
| 3  | 815787898 |
+----+------------+
.
.
.
|100 | 813454687 |
```

It 9 digits instead of 10. Because the leading '0' is missing. What should I do to remain the leading '0' after the random.

Comment: Maybe you should use a string type and not a number like CHAR ?
see this post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3200754/mysql-how-to-front-pad-zip-code-with-0)

Comment: Can I do a math with `CHAR`?

Comment: Do math first then convert to CHAR and pad with 0

Comment: Show me please, I'm not good at mysql. :(

Comment: See this http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15052/how-do-i-preserve-the-leading-zeros-when-i-insert-a-number-into-this-table and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17612920/lpad-with-leading-zero - Those should help to understand it a bit. One of those examples is `UPDATE t1 SET NUMER=LPAD(NUMER,6,'0')` - See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/11165118/ and http://stackoverflow.com/a/11165127/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like @B-and-P describes in his comment. You can do this using `LPAD`.

```
UPDATE 
    customer_db
SET
    number = LPAD(FLOOR(number + rand()*1000000),10,0)
```

LPAD uses 3 parameters; string, total amount of characters and last but not least which character should be used for padding.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is the kind of thoughtful answer I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to @Benz answer, you can try this (works on my end):

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (`NUMBER`)
VALUES 
(CONCAT('081',rand()*100000000))
```

table schema

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table1` (
`ID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`NUMBER` char(10) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Thank you very much B-and-P. This is a good idea for a start over a table. I'll note down for a future use.