# mysql auto_increment keep INT at 5

Tags: php, mysql, auto-increment

I want my columns PRIMARY key (which is `id` in my case) to be used as a EAN-Code.

To achieve that the barcode lenght (printed on paper) is always the same, I want my PRIMARY key to auto_increment but the INT should always stay at 5.
To make things a little more clear, I added a layout of how it SHOULD look in the end.

```
######################################
#   id   # description # stock # ... #
# ######   ###########   #####   ### #
#  10001 #    item 1   #  100  # ... #
#  10002 #    item 2   #   50  # ... #
#  ..... #    ......   #  ...  # ... #
#  10010 #    item 10  #   20  # ... #
#  10011 #    item 11  #  110  # ... #
######################################
```

What I did so far is to set `auto_increment` to start at `10001`. But as soon as `item 10` is reached, `INT` must be set to 6, because the `id` looks something like `100010` (notice the 6 digits).

Any ideas on this one ?

Comment: Why would you want to do this. You're effectively limiting the number of records this table can hold when you could easily add another column which keeps up with your 5 digit scheme.

Comment: If you need a custom increment scheme then `AUTO_INCREMENT` will not be adequate. You're on your own and must do this in application code or some awful, ugly trigger. Another approach is to pre-generate a million of these in the correct format then claim them one by one as you need them.

Comment: As one could propably guess, this is designed to be used in a kind of webshop. As the webshop is not handling more than ~200 items, this should not be considered as a "limitation". The problem is, that the space available for the printed barcode on the container is limited, thats why I need exactly 5 digits. Sounds pretty weird though, I know :-)

Comment: Just use a normal autoincrement and start it at 10001? Why would it go from 10009 to 1000010? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: Tried it this way @Don't Panic. No success. As soon as the 10th item was reached, an error occured because INT of column id was set to 5. After I've set INT to 6, it counted up to 100010. The 1000 in front of the id itself is ment to be a placeholder or some kind of threshold.

Comment: Anyway, solution found. Instead of 1000 to be used as a placeholder, I use LPAD with leading zeros now. Solution found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17612920/lpad-with-leading-zero
Thanks to @Jay Blanchard and all the others for the input :-)

Comment: Another, possible easier approach instead of using LPAD, is to just set the collumns attribute to `UNSIGNED ZEROFILL` and limit `INT` to 5. Done.